# Is the solid of revolution obtained by rotating $E\subset OZY$ Lebesgue-measurable when $E$ is Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset OZY$ a Lebesgue-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can I prove that the solid of revolution obtained by rotating $E$ around the $Z$ axis is a Lebesgue-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

**Here is my attempt:**

Since $E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists G\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ an open set $:E\subset G$ and $m(G\setminus E)<\varepsilon$. Then I prove that the solid of revolution obtained by rotating $G$ around the $Z$ axis is opened in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I called $E_r$ the solid of revolution obtained by rotating $E$ and $G_r$ the solid of revolution obtained by rotating $G$. What I tried next is to bound the $m^*(G_r\setminus E_r)$ with something dependig on $\varepsilon$ but I wasn't able.

What I have tried to achieve the latter is to suppose first that $E$ is bounded so that both $E$ and $G$ can be included inside an open ball $B((x_1,x_2);r)$ where $(x_1,x_2)\in E$ and $r>0$. Since $G_r$ is an open set, $G_r$ is Lebesgue-measurable so $m(G_r)=\displaystyle\int_{G}dm\leq\iint_{G}dydz\int_{x_1-r}^{x_1+r}dx=2m(G)r$

I have denoted by $m$ the Lebesgue measure and $m^*$ the Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: What is $OZY$ ?

Comment: The plane generated by the axes $OZ$ and $OY$.